# Signal Strength with pybluez on Windows 7

Tags: python, bluetooth

I found the MAC of my device with a simple python script using pybluez.
But I couldn't find a documentation or sample script to read the
signal strength of my bluetooth connection. I think I have to use the
_bluetooth library - but how?

Or any other suggestions to do this with python?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pyblueZ example for [inquiry with RSSI](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py)

That would show you RSSI of devices during discovery.  If you want RSSI during a live connection, there is an HCI command for getting RSSI.  You would have to use pybluz to open an HCI socket, and manually form the command packet and parse the results.  On linux bluez this is done by the command `hcitool rssi`.  You could see the source code to understand the packet formats.  Note this method only works during an active connection.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Will try it!

Comment: Link broken. Change for https://pybluez.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1/trunk/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py?